# Edit profile page with 3 tables - Yii frameworks

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

I am new on `Yii framework`, so please i need some help where to start.

What i need is, `action and module` to display a form to a user, which his will be able to edit is own profile (with profile picture), so i have 3 table

```
user_account || user_personal || user_general
```

how can i build a form that insert and update those 3 table at once?

i try this:

This is what i did, but its still not saving the data even into 1 table.

```
 public function actionUpdate() {
        $model = new ProfileUpdate();
        if(isset($_POST['ProfileUpdate']))
              {
              $model->attributes = $_POST['ProfileUpdate'];
                if($model->validate())
                {
                  $account = new Profile();
                  $account->userid = Yii::app()->user->id;
                  $account->name = $model->name;
                  $account->website = $model->website;
                  $account->category = $model->category;
                  $account->save();

                $this->redirect('profile');
                }

                }
```

model:

```
    class Profile extends CActiveRecord
{

    public $userid; 
    public $name;   
    public $website; 
    public $category;

  public static function model()
  {
    return parent::model(__CLASS__);
  }

  public function tableName()
  {
    return 'userinfo';
  }

  public function primaryKey()
  {
    return 'id';
  }

  public static function userExists($user)
  {
    return self::model()->countByAttributes( array('username'=>$user) ) > 0;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all three models in a single function

**for example:**

**In create function**

```
$model_account = new user_account;
$model_personal= new user_personal;
$model_general = new user_general;

$this->render('create',array(
            'model_account'=>$model_account, 'model_personal' => $model_personal, 'model_general' => $model_general
        ));
```

here the all three models pass by render to create page.

in form page you can use the every model attributes as fields

Like this

```
echo $form->textField($model_account,'account_name'); 
echo $form->textField($model_personal,'email');
echo $form->textField($model_general,'address');
```

**In create function / Update function**

```
$model_account->attributes = $_POST['user_account'];
$model_personal->attributes = $_POST['user_personal'];
$model_general->attributes = $_POST['user_general'];
if($model_account->validate() && $model_personal->validate() && $model_general->validate())
                {
                  $model_account->save();
                  $model_personal->save();
                  $model_general->save(); 
}
```